# Access MTP device via Powershell

Tags: powershell, mtp

I am trying to access the SD-card on my windows phone (Lumia 830) via a powershell script (windows 10, powershell version 5.0.10240.16384). But I am not able to do so. The phone does not appear as a PSDrive. This seems to be the case because the device is connected via the MTP (media transfer protocoll).

I can access the phone via the explorer without any problems but not via powershell.

I can get the wmi object of the phone via

```
Get-WmiObject -class win32_pnpentity -computername localhost | ? { $_.caption -Like "*myPhoneName*" }
```

But I don't know how to mount the device.

Is there any Powershell driver for MTP? Or any other alternative that I can use the powershell for scripting file operations to/from my phone?

Comment: I know you're using a Windows phone, but from all my research on this to date I can't see a way to do this consistently or at all on most MTP only devices (whether from Powershell, cmd.exe etc). This may be useful: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57429/open-command-prompt-to-access-folders-of-a-usb-connected-android-phone

Comment: @Kev : Thanks for the hint. I've already seen that. You are right that my main problem currently is with my windows phone, but i have a similar issue with my camera and maybe other devices in the future. Therefor I was hoping to find a more generic solution.